# Create single polyline from a road network

Tags: qgis, kml, network

I often need to create KML with a single polyline in order to organize bicycle riding group activities, sharing the KML so that every rider has the right path for that activity.

I usually trace the line over google satellite layer in QGIS, then export that polyline ("Export selected features as..." option in layer context menu).

The problem is: I constantly end up retracing the same parts of roads. For example, if one path goes A -> B -> C -> D, and other goes E -> B -> C -> F, I end up tracing two different paths which contain the same sub-segment, namely the B -> C segment (which might even be reversed, for example F -> C -> B -> E, but that part would still be the same.

I know of the concept of road networks, with nodes and "edges", so my question is how could I do the following:

1. Create a lot of individual polylines, that would be the parts of roads between the crossroads (these are mostly rural roads where you can turn in every direction);
2. Somehow inform QGIS that these polylines connect at corners;
3. Somehow create a sequence from these segments, that is "assemble" a larger path running along this sequence, and then *export* this as a single polyline in a KML file.

I know that I can create a kml by selecting every desired part and export it, but this multi-segment strategy would prevent the "navigate path" option of most mobile phone apps. So it would be much preferrable to create a single path, without permanently editing the source layer.

Comment: I dont understand. What data are you starting with? You cant trace a google satellite raster? You mean that you create a empty vector layer and edit/draw the line on top of it?

Comment: QGIS should have a function that combines a number of selected line segments into a single line (join/merge/intersect?).  So you could draw all your segments, and when you want to export a route, just select the series you want, create a single line element, and export that. This will likely require that the vertices on the end of each line segment match exactly, so you'll want to figure out how to use snapping tools when drawing the segments.

Comment: @BERA I have one raster layer (google satellite) and created one vector layer, so I manually draw on vector layer, using background raster as reference.

Comment: @C.A. well that is exactely what I want to learn how to do, supposing QGIS actually has the features you described.

Comment: @heltonbiker sounds like [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdissolve) is what you are looking for. It will dissolve all line segments into one